# How to intercept button taps?

Tags: iphone

How I tell which button is tapped the user in a view?
Is there a "aspect" way of capturing the events when a UIButton is clicked?

Basically, without any additonal code, I am able to capture all button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about views, but in a view controller, you can specify a method with the pattern as below:

```
- (IBAction)mybuttontapped:(id)sender;
```

You will need to connect your button in the interface builder for the desired event to the handler. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your button to an action in your view controller. When the user taps the button, it will execute the action.

Answer (score 0):

see the code below

```
 UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // add to a view
    [superView addSubview:myButton];
```

So all the click event on `myButton` will be received in `buttonClicked`  method,
Implement `buttonClicked` method ,

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
   UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*) sender;

   ........

   .......
}
```